# How to seach for specific instructions in an ELF binary

Tags: linux, assembly, elf

How do i search of a specific ASM instruction in an ELF executable?
eg. I want to check if the sequence `mov $0,%eax` in my executable. Are there any tools for this? Is there any tool which lets me search for the similar instructions which varies only by the register used? 
eg: It should match both `mov $0,%eax` as well as `move $0,%ecx`.

Comment: `objdump -d | egrep 'mov +\$0x0,%e'`

Comment: @Jester, that's the answer: you should post it as such.

Comment: FYI: There are other ways to set eax to zero.

Comment: It should be noted that a linear sweep disassembler (such as `objdump` suggested by @Jester) may miss some of the instructions. And you can search for `xor`/`sub` register zeroing with `objdump -d | egrep '(xor|sub) +(\%e[a-z][a-z]),\2'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resorted to two methods for the requirement. 
The easiest was objdump. Convert the binary to asm format using `objdump -S myexe > myexe.s` and use grep for the most basic type of search.

When my search requirements got advanced, for eg. find `jmp` instructions with `pop` instructions just before the jmp, i moved on to using ruby regexes instead of grep to keep track of jmp's and backtrack for pops.

But at times i had to scan through really large binaries ( 100 MB ) and the objdump ruby method was slow and getting killed by the kernel ( my script was very basic. bad scripting could be part of the reason. but it was still very slow )

I went through the code of `llvm-objdump` and tinkered around to keep track of when a particular opcode was occuring, when particular operands were occuring etc. Trust me, the existing code was very easy to understand and make modifications to. This modified objdump was tons faster and got the job done. I made the modofications to `DisassembleObject` where there is a

```
for (Index = Start; Index < End; Index += Size)
```

main loop which goes through each instruction in the executable. `Inst` is the name of the current instruction which you can do checks on and introduce your own code.